# Blender Texture Brush Paint Doesn't have Variety/ Falloff

Tags: texture-painting

I’m wondering, I have the newest 2.90.1 Blender.  My Texture Paint Brush doesn’t seem to give me any variety of falloff/ strokeà as shown in the owl tutorial. Wondering if this is a GPU issue (I have GTX 970) or possibly just missing an option in Tools Tab?

**Also SHIFT + S does nothing on my end.

*The purple owl is mine, his is the brown in tutorial

Link to Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eX3skhOOmco

Thank you for your time, be safe,
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the video there is `Size Pressure` for the radius activated. You can see it in the screenshot. It's the little icon behind the radius editbox on the top of the screen. `Size Pressure` **only works with drawing tablets** where you can control the pressure with the pen.

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> activates `Stabilize Stroke` under [Stroke](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/brush/stroke.html) settings. It adds a delay between the cursor and the stroke shown by a line. Painting with it feels like dragging a plow and you can draw smoother lines.

Comment: YES! Thank you very much. This worked! I'll try to look at the little details/ read the interface more thoroughly next time.